# Access SQL: Select from table if ID is in another

Tags: sql, ms-access

Say I have the table T1:

```
ID | PNo | MM   | CP | Flag | Name |
---|-----|------|----|------|------|
1  | 13  | True | 4  |  A   |  X   |
1  | 92  | True | 3  |  A   |  X   |
2  | 1   | True | 3  |  B   |  Y   |
2  | 13  | False| 2  |  A   |  Y   |
3  | 13  | True | 3  |  B   |  W   |
4  | 1   | True | 3  |  B   |  Z   |
```

And T2:

```
ID | PNo | MM   | CP |
---|-----|------|----|
1  | 13  | True | 4  |
2  | 92  | True | 3  |
3  | 1   | True | 3  |
4  | 13  | False| 2  |
5  | 13  | True | 3  |
1  | 1   | False| 3  |
```

What I want to do is to do a INSERT INTO where I take values of T1 and T2 but only if the ID of T2 is in T1 and if T1 has the flag with the value A.

I have tried two things:

1) INNER JOIN: Something like

```
INSERT INTO T3 (ID, PNo, MM, CP, Flag, Name)
SELECT T1.ID, T2.PNo, T2.MM, T2.CP, 'A', T1.Name 
FROM T2 INNER JOIN T1 ON T1.ID = T2.ID 
WHERE (T1.FLAG = 'A')
```

The problem here is that it literally takes every combination of all relevant rows from T1 and T2. What I want is, I only want to take those rows of T2 whose IDs are also in T1.

2) IN?

```
INSERT INTO T3 (ID, PNo, MM, CP, Flag, Name)
SELECT T1.ID, T2.PNo, T2.MM, T2.CP, 'A', T1.Name
FROM T2, T1 
WHERE T2.ID IN 
      (SELECT ID FROM T1 WHERE Flag = 'X')
```

Problem here is, this takes foreeeeeeeeeeever!

Is there not a more sophisticated method for this?

edit:// Changed a value in T2 so that the example is more meaningful.

So what I want in the new table T3 is:

```
ID | PNo | MM   | CP | Flag | Name |
---|-----|------|----|------|------|
1  | 13  | True | 4  |  A   |  X   |
1  | 1   | False| 3  |  A   |  X   |
2  | 1   | True | 3  |  A   |  Y   |
```

What I get instead is:

```
ID | PNo | MM   | CP | Flag | Name |
---|-----|------|----|------|------|
1  | 13  | True | 4  |  A   |  X   |
1  | 1   | False| 3  |  A   |  X   |
1  | 13  | True | 4  |  A   |  X   |
1  | 1   | False| 3  |  A   |  X   |
2  | 1   | True | 3  |  A   |  Y   |
```

So basically for all T1 values that I select (ID, Name) and for all corresponding rows that I can match by ID in T2, I get every combination.

Comment: Row `1  | 92  | True | 3  |  A   |  X` is causing the doubling. If you join `T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.PNo  = T2.PNo` then `1  | 1   | False| 3  |  A   |  X  ` won't be in the result. I guess something is wrong with your expectations.

Comment: ok, there are two names in T1 for T2.id = 1 (in your case the same 'X', but I guess it does not have to be always the case) . Which one do you need on the output and why?

Comment: Maybe it get clearer if I give a bit of context. T1 basically has values that are not accurate (except for Name) BUT it has all IDs that I need the information for. T2 on the other hands has too many IDs than I need but has the accurate values.

So what I want to do is, from T1 I want to extract the information what rows I need from T2 and what their respective names are. From T2 then I will assign the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

Your second solution is almost right, however, you perform cartesian product unnecessarily (I'm not surprised that it takes forever). Try this one and if it is slow then create an index on `Flag`.

```
INSERT INTO T3 (ID, PNo, MM, CP, Flag, Name)
SELECT *
FROM T2 
WHERE T2.ID IN 
  (SELECT ID FROM T1 WHERE Flag = 'X')
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply! The problem is that I need to take also a value from T1.

Comment: @nvrslnc I dare to say, that your first query is correct. It should return only those rows from T2 having ID in T1 such that T1.flag is equal to 'A' (due to the inner join).

Comment: Hey, I have just tried this again on a smaller table. I really do get every combination. So if a column of T1 has two rows with the value A and T2 has the values Y, Z where all those rows of T2 has the same ID as in T1, then I get the combination (A, Y), (A, Z), (A, Y), (A, Z).

Comment: @nvrslnc could you extend your question that it includes the result of the first query for your data and say what is wrong with it?

Comment: Sure, let me edit the tables so that the problem is more apparent.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
INSERT INTO T3 (ID, PNo, MM, CP, Flag, Name)
    SELECT T2.ID, T2.PNo, T2.MM, T2.CP, ?, "A"
    FROM T2
    WHERE T2.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM T1 WHERE Flag = "A");
```

You are selecting `T1.ID` in your first query.  You can take either `T1.ID` or `T2.ID`, because you are requiring that they be equal.

You can do this with a `JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO T3 (ID, PNo, MM, CP, Flag, Name)
    SELECT T2.ID, T2.PNo, T2.MM, T2.CP, T1.Name, "A"
    FROM T2 INNER JOIN
         T1
         ON T2.ID = T1.ID;
```

If this is generating duplicates, then you have multiple rows in `T1` for a given `name`.

Comment: I forgot one value: I also need the Name value from T1, as T2 has no such field. So I do actually need to mention T1 in the outer query, I think?